# My databinding fails, is the path wrong?

Tags: windows-phone-7, data-binding, mvvm

I'm trying to create a simple RSS news aggregator. But I've done something wrong with the binding.

The xaml:

```
<phone:LongListSelector 
       x:Name="MainLongListSelector" 
       Margin="0,0,-12,0" 
       ItemsSource="{Binding Path=News.List}"     
       SelectionChanged="MainLongListSelector_SelectionChanged">
```

The code behind:

```
   (mainpage)
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // Set the data context of the LongListSelector control 
        // to the sample data
        DataContext = App.ViewModel;


   (viewmodel)
   public class NewsViewModel : BaseViewModel
   {
        public NewsRepository News { get; private set; }
   }
```

The `NewsRepository`  is just an model object holding the `List<obj> List`. Could anyone point me in the direction where thing goes sideways?

The app runs just fine but the single item in the List I've put in manually does not show up in the application :-(

I've set and breakpoint at the assignment of the `DataContext` to the the viewmodels content its there...

Comment: Hard to tell without more code. Show your longlistselector item template, News.List and the object definition inside News.List object.

Comment: Agree with @AlaaMasoud, can you please post more of your code. Is App.ViewModel an instance of NewsViewModel? Does NewsRepository have a List property?

Answer (score 0):

1. Both `NewsViewModel` and `NewsRepository` have to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`.
2. It would be easier if you use `ObservableCollection<obj>` as a source of your binding instead of custom `NewsRepository` object.